# C. My digits are printing (in English) in reverse order? How can I fix this?

Tags: c, cs50

A little help please! I am working through the exercises in the book, 'Programming in C'.

I have to write a program that takes in an integer and then extracts and displays each digit of the integer in English.

So if I type in 1234, it should print back 'one two three four'.

Due to this exercise being towards the beginning of the book, it has not yet taught arrays, functions, pointers or strings. Which I assume means I'm not allowed to use any of them. So I have to somehow solve it with a pretty limited amount of options.

What I have written works more or less BUT, the numbers are printed back in REVERSE order. I'm really struggling to find an alternative and have been playing around with the code for the past couple of others.

I realize there is another very similar question posted a couple of years ago, but I'm limited even further with what I can do in this problem, not to mention, his/her problem was significantly more complex.

I'd really appreciate it if you could take a look and offer up some suggestions.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int digit;

    //Accept integer
    printf("Choose a number.\n");

    int num = GetInt();

     // adding minus to the beginning if int is negative
    if (num < 0) 
    {
        num = -num;
        printf("minus ");
    }

    // isolate each digit from integer and then print in english

    do
    {
        digit = num % 10;

        switch(digit)
        {
            case 0:
                printf("Zero ");
                break;
            case 1:
                printf("One ");
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("Two ");
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("Three ");
                break;
            case 4:
                printf("Four ");
                break;
            case 5:
                printf("Five ");
                break;
            case 6:
                printf("Six ");
                break;
            case 7:
                printf("Seven ");
                break;
            case 8:
                printf("Eight ");
                break;
            case 9:
                printf("Nine ");
                break;
            case 10:
                printf("Ten ");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        num /= 10; 

    } while(num != 0);

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger and watch the variables carefully. That is elementary maths, not even related to programming.

Comment: "*What I have written works ...*" You want to say you wrote this code and don't know what is does?`:-S

Comment: Err, `10` isn't a digit.

Comment: I should've been clearer, I know WHY but I can't work out an alternative. I'm just working off of what I've been taught so far in the book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you cannot use recursion, since you cannot define your own functions, you need an initial loop to find the leftmost digit position.

The following code uses the `place` variable to hold 10 raised to the 'number of digits minus 1', treating zero as a single digit number. The main loop divides the (remaining part of the) number by `place`, prints out that digit, then reduces the number modulo `place` and divides `place` by 10 for the next iteration until all digits have been printed (when `place` is zero).

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int digit;

    //Accept integer
    printf("Choose a number.\n");

    int num = GetInt();

    // adding minus to the beginning if int is negative
    if (num < 0) 
    {
        num = -num;
        printf("minus ");
    }

    // get 10 to the power of 'number of digits minus 1'
    int place;

    for (place = 1; place <= num / 10; place *= 10)
        ;

    // isolate each digit from integer and then print in english

    do
    {
        digit = num / place;

        switch(digit)
        {
        case 0:
            printf("Zero ");
            break;
        case 1:
            printf("One ");
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Two ");
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Three ");
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("Four ");
            break;
        case 5:
            printf("Five ");
            break;
        case 6:
            printf("Six ");
            break;
        case 7:
            printf("Seven ");
            break;
        case 8:
            printf("Eight ");
            break;
        case 9:
            printf("Nine ");
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        num %= place;
        place /= 10; 

    } while (place != 0);

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: This is an awesomely elegant fix, thank you and I've tested it to know it works. However, I feel I need to understand it fully before I just implement it and move on!

Can you quickly elaborate on how you came to this solution? 

Also, how I can see you used a 'for loop', yet there is no body to it. How does that work? I did not know that was possible.

Comment: @MattCleary I suggest you just run through the loops on paper, writing out the num, place and digit variables as they change. The tricky parts are in the loop that determines the initial value of `place`. It is important to do the comparison as `place <= num / 10` rather than `place * 10 <= num` in order to avoid arithmetic overflow for large numbers, and it's important to use `<=` rather than `<` to avoid an "off-by-one iteration" error when `num` happens to be a power of 10.

Comment: @MattCleary The body of a `for` loop can be a single statement with a terminating semicolon, or a block in braces. The same is true for other control statements such as `if`, `else` etc. In this case, I used an empty statement followed by a semicolon. It would probably be more noticeable to place the empty statement indented on the following line, so I'll edit the answer to do that. It is also possible to replace the empty statement with an empty block.

Comment: Okay, so if there's nothing inside of the for loop

Let's assume num = 1234

Place = 1, 
It's obviously smaller than 1234

There's nothing inside of the for loop, so then place = place(1) * 10.

So place == 10?

Why not just say int place = 10;?

Sorry for my idiocy.

Comment: What is in the scope of the for loop? Nothing below it?

Comment: @MattCleary If num = 1234, the for loop does: place = 1, 1 <= 1234/10 /*true*/, /*empty statement*/, place = 10, 10 <= 1234/10 /*true*/, /*empty statement*/, place = 100, 100 <= 1234/10 /*true*/, /*empty statement*/, place = 1000, 1000 <= 1234/10 /*false*/. So place ends up as 1000 after the for loop. The scope of the for loop is irrelevant since it doesn't declare anything. "Scope" has a precise meaning in C related to the visibility of identifiers but perhaps you were using the word in a different context, such as "where does the for loop extend to?" That's the end of the attached statement.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
    digit = num % 10;
```

as the first statement under the `do` loop.

When `num` is equal to `1234`, the value of `digit` will be `4`. Hence, you end up printing `four` first.

It will be easier to print `one two three four` if you use a recursive function.

Here's my suggestion:

```
void printNumber(int num, int level)
{
   // Break the recursion.
   if ( num == 0 )
   {
      if (level == 0)
      {
         // Make sure to print Zero when the original number is 0.
         printf("Zero ");
      }
      return;
   }

   // Recursive call to print the most significant digit first.
   printNumber (num/10, level+1); 

   int digit = num % 10;

   switch(digit)
   {
      case 0:
         printf("Zero ");
         break;
      case 1:
         printf("One ");
         break;
      case 2:
         printf("Two ");
         break;
      case 3:
         printf("Three ");
         break;
      case 4:
         printf("Four ");
         break;
      case 5:
         printf("Five ");
         break;
      case 6:
         printf("Six ");
         break;
      case 7:
         printf("Seven ");
         break;
      case 8:
         printf("Eight ");
         break;
      case 9:
         printf("Nine ");
         break;
      default:
         break;
   }
}

int main (void)
{
    int digit;

    //Accept integer
    printf("Choose a number.\n");

    int num = GetInt();

     // adding minus to the beginning if int is negative
    if (num < 0) 
    {
        num = -num;
        printf("minus ");
    }

    // isolate each digit from integer and then print in english
    printNumber(num, 0);

    printf("\n");
}
```

**Update**

If you are not able to use a recursive function, you will need to use a different strategy than what you have in your question. Here's one that stores the digits in an array and prints them in the right order.

```
int main (void)
{
   int digits[20]; // Make it large enough
   int count = 0;

   int digit;

   //Accept integer
   printf("Choose a number.\n");

   int num = GetInt();

   // adding minus to the beginning if int is negative
   if (num < 0) 
   {
      num = -num;
      printf("minus ");
   }

   do
   {
      digit = num % 10;
      digits[count] = digit;
      ++count;
      num /= 10;
   } while ( num > 0 );

   for ( int i = count-1; i >= 0; --i )
   {
      digit = digits[i];
      switch(digit)
      {
         case 0:
            printf("Zero ");
            break;
         case 1:
            printf("One ");
            break;
         case 2:
            printf("Two ");
            break;
         case 3:
            printf("Three ");
            break;
         case 4:
            printf("Four ");
            break;
         case 5:
            printf("Five ");
            break;
         case 6:
            printf("Six ");
            break;
         case 7:
            printf("Seven ");
            break;
         case 8:
            printf("Eight ");
            break;
         case 9:
            printf("Nine ");
            break;
         default:
            break;
      }
   }

   printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to solve this via creating functions unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry I can't use arrays either :( Unless the author was hoping I'd read ahead and use the concepts in the later chapters.

Comment: @MattCleary, I hope the solutions I provided will help you find something that works for you.

Comment: @RSahu Both of your programs here don't handle an entry of just 0 properly. In the array version of the program change the while loop to a do loop.

Answer (score 0):

`digit = num % 10;` followed by `num /= 10;` will grab each digit in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

Because `digit = num % 10;` returns the last digit of the integer.

For e.g., If your number is 1234, then it will return value `4`.

Hence, it is printing numbers in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

loop 1:
  1234 % 10 = 4

so it prints 4 first. Is it clear enough?

Answer (score 0):

First reverse the number and then the same code will work.